# Using apostrophes in Django settings.py when telling the location of the templates directory

Tags: python, django, web, jinja2

I need to say where the templates file is for my Django app and my user file has an apostrophe in it. Can someone help me out with this one?

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ["/Users/Harry's PC/Desktop/django_tutorials/mySite/personal"],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Then the exception type is: TemplateDoesNotExist when running the server.

Comment: The full error message will show the name of the template that does not exist, and the directories that Django searched. It is common to use something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to avoid hardcoding the path to the project directory - we can't give you a specific answer because you haven't shown the project layout.

Comment: Also, you've tagged the question `jinja2`, but you use the regular `DjangoTemplates` backend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to escape it with a backslash. You probably have to escape the space, too.

Of course, the easiest thing to do is rename the file without the special characters. No apostrophes and either camelcase or underscore for the spaces.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': ["/Users/Harry\'s\ PC/Desktop/django_tutorials/mySite/personal"],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```